# Flexbox item does not vertically align as expected when container has a fixed height in iE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have a flexbox vertical align problem in IE11.

I have a flexbox container an a child. I have an image inside the item div.The image is bigger than the flex container, so I want to show the middle part of the image, using justify-content: center; This works as I expect in all browsers but IE11. The attached illustration should show the issue. Any help is appreciated.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="image.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please review and comment on my answer, and let me know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 is buggy when it comes to Flexbox, and in this case it doesn't what other browsers does.

When in a flex column direction, use `transform: translate()` to make it behave.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

/* IE11 only */
_:-ms-fullscreen, :root .IE11Fix {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item IE11Fix">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x300/f00" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistakenly using `justify-content: center` and `flex-direction: column`;

In a flex **column**, The *X axis alignment* is controlled by `align-items`, and the *Y axis alignment* is controlled by `justify-content`

If you **remove** `flex-direction: column` and **set** your container to be `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`, both work in the same way with the result you expected:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s3Lmqndu/1/